# I will like to restart the id of multiple data fetched from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a code in my controller which fetches data from database based on a criteria. I want to echo the index of the item in the array

```
public function history($id){
  $msg= whatsapp::where('claim_id', $id)->get();
  return view('history', compact(['msg'']));      
}
```

Below is my for each loop.

```
@foreach($msg as $msg)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$msg->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$msg->created_at}}</td>
    <td>{{$msg->tel}}</td>
    <td>{{$msg->message}} <br>{{$msg->files}}</td>>                      
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

I want the numberint to start from 1 no matter the id of the message.

Comment: `@foreach($msg as $index => $msg)`?

Comment: TYPO `compact(['msg''])`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Why am "I" hearing *La-la-la's* ?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Nice tune though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply wanting to echo the index of the array / collection in your blade template, try this:

```
@foreach($msgs as $key => $msg)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $key + 1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ $msg->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $msg->created_at }}</td>
        <td>{{ $msg->tel }}</td>
        <td>{{ $msg->message }} <br>{{ $msg->files }}</td>                      
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You missed something. Look at comments up there ;-)

Comment: Good spot, i hadn't seen that. Works if the guy wants a zero index, but I think you'll find he wants to start from 1 :P

Comment: Sure thing :) [This comment by Riggs...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61209852/i-will-like-to-restart-the-id-of-multiple-data-fetched-from-database#comment108284467_61209852).